# Will the code have any impact on MySQL available connections?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, datasource

I have developed a Java web application which connects to MySQL Database using JDBC connector and making the pool of 2 connections. The application is deployed on tomcat server.

Mmy question is, does this code impacts to MySQL available connections if I deploy the application multiple times and the code doesn't have any line to close the available connection when I am shutting down the tomcat? Does tomcat take care of closing the connections when getting restarted?

Connection Util:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;

public class MySQLConnectionPool {


     public static DataSource setUpPool(){

         GenericObjectPool gPool = null;
         String dbName = "DBName";
         String userName = "Username";
         String password = "Password";
         String hostname = "Host";
         String port = "Port";
         try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Creates an Instance of GenericObjectPool That Holds Our Pool of Connections Object!
                gPool = new GenericObjectPool();
                gPool.setMaxActive(2);

                // Creates a ConnectionFactory Object Which Will Be Use by the Pool to Create the Connection Object!
                ConnectionFactory cf = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory("jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, userName, password);

                // Creates a PoolableConnectionFactory That Will Wraps the Connection Object Created by the ConnectionFactory to Add Object Pooling Functionality!
                PoolableConnectionFactory pcf = new PoolableConnectionFactory(cf, gPool, null, null, false, true);
         }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             System.out.println("Error: "+e.toString());
        }

            return new PoolingDataSource(gPool);
     }

}
```

DAO:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<User> getUserDetails(String environment, String MySQLQuery) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    Connection connObj = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {   
        DataSource dataSource = MySQLConnectionPool.setUpPool();

        // Performing Database Operation!
        System.out.println("\n=====Making A New Connection Object For Db Transaction=====\n");
        connObj = dataSource.getConnection();

        stmt = connObj.createStatement();
        result = stmt.executeQuery(MySQLQuery);
        while(result.next()) {
            //Some code here
        }

        System.out.println("\n=====Releasing Connection Object To Pool=====\n");            
    } catch(Exception sqlException) {

    } finally {
        try {
            // Closing ResultSet Object
            if(result != null) {
                result.close();
            }
            // Closing Statement Object
            if(stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            // Closing Connection Object
            if(connObj != null) {
                connObj.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception sqlException) {

        }
    }
    return users;
}
```

Comment: You should define one and only one connection pool, your current code is creating a new pool on each call to `MySQLConnectionPool.setUpPool()`. That is an accident waiting to happen. Also consider looking at the datasource/connection pool support that is built-in in tomcat instead of trying to (badly) roll you own solution. Also learn about try-with-resources: your current resource handling is brittle and unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks!! 
If I change the maxActive to 1, will the issue get resolved for me? I am pretty new in Java and don't know how to make sure that this code shouldn't impact my production DB.

Comment: My main point is that what you are currently doing is entirely the wrong approach, reducing the maxActive to 1 is just a trivial change to a bad solution. For a better approach, see the Tomcat 9 documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html or consider using something like Spring or Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the entire tomcat, then your connection to the database will be closed because the java executable running Tomcat will release the connection when stopping.

Even if you don't stop the server, if Java decides that your `Connection` object is no longer used, then it will be garbage collected. You just don't know when.

On another notes:

- You should probably look for ways to embed `DataSource` onto the server and obtain `DataSource` from the server: this [page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) may help.
- You should rewrite your code to use *try with resources* (Java 7++) which take care on closing your resource correctly (your code is wrong).

With *try with resources*:

```
DataSource dataSource = MySQLConnectionPool.setUpPool();
try (Connection connObj = dataSource.getConnection()) {   
  try (Statement stmt = connObj.createStatement()) {
    try (ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(MySQLQuery)) {
      while(result.next()) {
        //Some code here
      }
    }
  } 
} catch (SQLException sqlException) {
  // do something
}
```

Or:

```
DataSource dataSource = MySQLConnectionPool.setUpPool();
try (Connection connObj = dataSource.getConnection();
     Statement stmt = connObj.createStatement();
     ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(MySQLQuery)
    ) {
  while(result.next()) {
    //Some code here
  }
} catch (SQLException sqlException) {
  // do something
}
```

As I stated above, your code is wrong because you may have an exception (at least, a `SQLException`) when closing the `ResultSet`, or a `Statement`, so the later object would never be released by your code:

```
    try {
        // Closing ResultSet Object
        if(result != null) {
            result.close(); // if it fails, stmt and connObj are not closed.
        }
        // Closing Statement Object
        if(stmt != null) {
            stmt.close(); // if it fails, connObj is not closed.
        }
        // Closing Connection Object
        if(connObj != null) {
            connObj.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception sqlException) {

    }
```

If you can't use *try with resources* (Java 6 is presumably no longer supported since decades, but who knows), then your code code should looks like:

```
Connection connObj = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet result = null;
try {
  // ... do whatever is needed
} finally {
  if(result != null) {
    try {result.close();} catch (Exception ignored) {}
  }
  if(stmt != null) {
    try {stmt.close();} catch (Exception ignored) {}
  }
  if(connObj != null) {
    try {connObj .close();} catch (Exception ignored) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: 'Then they will' what?

Comment: it was referring to the database connection.

Comment: Thanks @NoDataFound!!

I have implemented the try with resources in my code. Also, I have gone through the tomcat link which you have provided; the tomcat is suggesting to use the JNDI which stores the DB details in tomcat xml. But I am connecting multiple DB from one application and the server where I have deployed the code is publically accessible with other persons and can't store the DB credentials in xml. Do you have any other way where I can create my connection pool internally from the application where I have decryption to decrypt the password and use that there?

Comment: This was only an advice. If you need to create connection because your client/user pass as parameter some login/password to connect to some db then you probably don't even need a datasource (think about it: a datasource advantage is to reuse connections already made because connecting to a db take some time).